# Matrix of sums, across all variables in a dataframe

Tags: r

I want to create a matrix with sums (or counts) of values in each variable
Here is some sample data.

```
set.seed(123)
a <- sample(0:1, 50, replace = TRUE)
b <- sample(0:1, 50, replace = TRUE)
c <- sample(0:1, 50, replace = TRUE)
d <- sample(0:1, 50, replace = TRUE)
e <- sample(0:1, 50, replace = TRUE)

df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e)
```

df has 5 variables, where 1= yes, 0=no. I'd like the overlap of the yes variables.

I'd like to get to a 5x5 matrix/dataframe with the rows a to e, and columns a to e, with the sum of the values, in the cells. Much like a correlation matrix but with sums instead of coefficients. I guess this is either sum or count as the values are 1.

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you need `t(df) %*% as.matrix(df)`

Comment: @akrun, that's exactly what I needed fantastic! Is there also a simple way to convert this to %?, where the values are vertical %, the diagonal values are 100% .

Comment: @akrun, I think i've figured the % thing with a hack. Many many thanks for the solution